# angular ngif statement adding more conditions

Tags: angular, angular-ng-if

I have a condition like this.

```
<div *ngIf="data$  | async as data; else loading">
```

I wanted to add additional condition into above statement, how am I able to do that?

`<div *ngIf="data$ && isLoading | async as data; else loading" >` error

`<div *ngIf="data$ | async as data && isLoading ; else loading" >` error

also for the | operator what is the name called I tried to google it but no result found. Or operator, signle line operator, line operator?

Comment: what about using parens around the observable...`*ngIf="(data$ | async as data) && !isLoading ; else loading"`?  And the `|` is called pipe.

Comment: I tried it. The error shows `Expected identifier or keyword expression expected` after `data` and between `async and as` it says `)` expected

Answer (score 1):

I want to suggest handling only one variable on if statements, hence you can handle only data$ as your condition to evaluate and handle the other conditions on your observable/promise.

Example:

```html
<!-- on my template this looks cleaner -->
<div *ngIf="myObservable$  | async as data; else loading">
```

```js
myObservable$ = of({}).pipe(
  map((response) => response && this.isLoading) // <- here I evaluate my conditions
)
```

However, if you want to evaluate your conditions on the template then you can:

```html
<div *ngIf="(data$ | async) && isLoading; else loading">
```